# c++ compilation terminal in file included error/warning

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a c++ program that outputs what seems to be what I want but i am unsure if the values are correct as some of them are constantly zero which seems a bit suspicious to me. The program uses a C++ implementation of Giraffe found on github at https://github.com/enlighter/giraffe/tree/f3609a7b20d9817bdc543db6832148f26524c298 . The only thing weird that i noticed is that when i compile using VSC, i get a bunch of messages in the terminal prior to the output. I think they are warnings? but i'm not sure as it is my first time using VSC. Below is a log dump of what appears in the terminal. The correct output starts from `GLOBAL 0;` onwards in the screenshot.

```
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/Core:302,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\matrix_ops.h:23,
                 from ann/ann.h:39,
                 from ann/features_conv.h:29,
                 from own.cpp:43:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:60:39: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument '__m128' [-Wignored-attributes]
   60 | template<> struct is_arithmetic<__m128>  { enum { value = true }; };
      |                                       ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:61:40: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument '__m128i' [-Wignored-attributes]
   61 | template<> struct is_arithmetic<__m128i> { enum { value = true }; };
      |                                        ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:62:40: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument '__m128d' [-Wignored-attributes]
   62 | template<> struct is_arithmetic<__m128d> { enum { value = true }; };
      |                                        ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:147:43: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::Packet4f' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes]
  147 | template<> struct unpacket_traits<Packet4f> { typedef float  type; enum {size=4}; typedef Packet4f half; };
      |                                           ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:148:43: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::Packet2d' {aka '__m128d'} [-Wignored-attributes]
  148 | template<> struct unpacket_traits<Packet2d> { typedef double type; enum {size=2}; typedef Packet2d half; };
      |                                           ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:149:43: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::Packet4i' {aka '__m128i'} [-Wignored-attributes]
  149 | template<> struct unpacket_traits<Packet4i> { typedef int    type; enum {size=4}; typedef Packet4i half; };
      |                                           ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:468:37: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::Packet4f' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes]
  468 | struct protate_impl<offset, Packet4f>
      |                                     ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:476:37: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::Packet4i' {aka '__m128i'} [-Wignored-attributes]
  476 | struct protate_impl<offset, Packet4i>
      |                                     ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:484:37: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::Packet2d' {aka '__m128d'} [-Wignored-attributes]
  484 | struct protate_impl<offset, Packet2d>
      |                                     ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:756:35: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::Packet4f' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes]
  756 | struct palign_impl<Offset,Packet4f>
      |                                   ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:779:35: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::Packet4i' {aka '__m128i'} [-Wignored-attributes]
  779 | struct palign_impl<Offset,Packet4i>
      |                                   ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:802:35: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::Packet2d' {aka '__m128d'} [-Wignored-attributes]
  802 | struct palign_impl<Offset,Packet2d>
      |                                   ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:816:34: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::Packet4f' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes]
  816 | ptranspose(PacketBlock<Packet4f,4>& kernel) {
      |                                  ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:821:34: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::Packet2d' {aka '__m128d'} [-Wignored-attributes]
  821 | ptranspose(PacketBlock<Packet2d,2>& kernel) {
      |                                  ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:828:34: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::Packet4i' {aka '__m128i'} [-Wignored-attributes]
  828 | ptranspose(PacketBlock<Packet4i,4>& kernel) {
      |                                  ^
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/Core:304:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/Complex.h:233:63: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::Packet4f' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes]
  233 | template<> struct conj_helper<Packet4f, Packet2cf, false,false>
      |                                                               ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/Complex.h:242:63: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::Packet4f' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes]
  242 | template<> struct conj_helper<Packet2cf, Packet4f, false,false>
      |                                                               ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/Complex.h:435:63: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::Packet2d' {aka '__m128d'} [-Wignored-attributes]
  435 | template<> struct conj_helper<Packet2d, Packet1cd, false,false>
      |                                                               ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/Complex.h:444:63: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::Packet2d' {aka '__m128d'} [-Wignored-attributes]
  444 | template<> struct conj_helper<Packet1cd, Packet2d, false,false>
      |                                                               ^
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/Core:328:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h: In instantiation of 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>':
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:282:7:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 1>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:519:7:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 3>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:426:8:   required from 'struct Eigen::internal::special_scalar_op_base<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, float, float, false>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:41:34:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:48:34:   required from 'class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:91:7:   required from 'class Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:128:7:   required from 'class Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Geometry/Quaternion.h:283:16:   required from 'class Eigen::Quaternion<float>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Geometry/arch/Geometry_SSE.h:22:3:   required from here
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:55:30: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<float>::type' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes] 
   55 |                      >::type PacketReturnType;
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/Core:344:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h: In instantiation of 'class Eigen::DenseStorage<float, 4, 4, 1, 0>':
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:129:113:   required from 'class Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:128:7:   required from 'class Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Geometry/Quaternion.h:283:16:   required from 'class Eigen::Quaternion<float>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Geometry/arch/Geometry_SSE.h:22:3:   required from here
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:38:38: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<float>::type' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes]    
   38 |          bool Match     =  bool((Size%unpacket_traits<Packet>::size)==0),
      |                                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:39:33: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<float>::type' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes]    
   39 |          bool TryHalf   =  bool(int(unpacket_traits<Packet>::size) > 1)
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:40:33: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<float>::type' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes]    
   40 |                         && bool(int(unpacket_traits<Packet>::size) > int(unpacket_traits<typename unpacket_traits<Packet>::half>::size)) >
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:40:70: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<float>::type' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes]    
   40 |                         && bool(int(unpacket_traits<Packet>::size) > int(unpacket_traits<typename unpacket_traits<Packet>::half>::size)) >
      |                                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:40:70: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::unpacket_traits<__vector(4) float>::half' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:64:60: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<float>::type' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes]    
   64 |           int Alignment = (MatrixOrArrayOptions&DontAlign) ? 0
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
   65 |                         : compute_default_alignment<T,Size>::value >
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h: In instantiation of 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1>, 0>':
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:282:7:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1>, 1>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:519:7:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1>, 3>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:426:8:   required from 'struct Eigen::internal::special_scalar_op_base<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1>, double, double, false>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:41:34:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:48:34:   required from 'class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:91:7:   required from 'class Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:128:7:   required from 'class Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Geometry/Quaternion.h:283:16:   required from 'class Eigen::Quaternion<double>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Geometry/arch/Geometry_SSE.h:75:3:   required from here
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:55:30: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type' {aka '__m128d'} [-Wignored-attribute 
]
   55 |                      >::type PacketReturnType;
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h: In instantiation of 'class Eigen::DenseStorage<double, 4, 4, 1, 0>':
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:129:113:   required from 'class Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:128:7:   required from 'class Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Geometry/Quaternion.h:283:16:   required from 'class Eigen::Quaternion<double>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Geometry/arch/Geometry_SSE.h:75:3:   required from here
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:38:38: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type' {aka '__m128d'} [-Wignored-attributes]  
   38 |          bool Match     =  bool((Size%unpacket_traits<Packet>::size)==0),
      |                                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:39:33: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type' {aka '__m128d'} [-Wignored-attributes]  
   39 |          bool TryHalf   =  bool(int(unpacket_traits<Packet>::size) > 1)
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:40:33: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type' {aka '__m128d'} [-Wignored-attributes]  
   40 |                         && bool(int(unpacket_traits<Packet>::size) > int(unpacket_traits<typename unpacket_traits<Packet>::half>::size)) >
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:40:70: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type' {aka '__m128d'} [-Wignored-attributes]  
   40 |                         && bool(int(unpacket_traits<Packet>::size) > int(unpacket_traits<typename unpacket_traits<Packet>::half>::size)) >
      |                                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:40:70: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::unpacket_traits<__vector(2) double>::half' {aka '__m128d'} [-Wignored-attributes]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:64:60: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type' {aka '__m128d'} [-Wignored-attributes]  
   64 |           int Alignment = (MatrixOrArrayOptions&DontAlign) ? 0
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
   65 |                         : compute_default_alignment<T,Size>::value >
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h: In instantiation of 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1>, 0>':
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:282:7:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1>, 1>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:519:7:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1>, 3>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:426:8:   required from 'struct Eigen::internal::special_scalar_op_base<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1>, float, float, false>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:41:34:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:48:34:   required from 'class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:91:7:   required from 'class Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:128:7:   required from 'class Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/Map.h:75:53:   required from 'struct Eigen::internal::traits<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1> > >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/util/ForwardDeclarations.h:32:48:   required from 'struct Eigen::internal::accessors_level<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1> > >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/util/ForwardDeclarations.h:116:75:   required from 'class Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\matrix_ops.h:169:52:   required from here
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:55:30: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<float>::type' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes] 
   55 |                      >::type PacketReturnType;
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h: In instantiation of 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1> >, 0>':
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:282:7:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1> >, 1>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:519:7:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1> >, 3>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:426:8:   required from 'struct Eigen::internal::special_scalar_op_base<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1> >, float, float, false>'        
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:41:34:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1> > >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:48:34:   required from 'class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1> > >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/MapBase.h:27:34:   required from 'class Eigen::MapBase<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1> >, 0>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/MapBase.h:171:34:   required from 'class Eigen::MapBase<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1> >, 1>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/Map.h:89:79:   required from 'class Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, -1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\matrix_ops.h:169:52:   required from here
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:55:30: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<float>::type' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes] 
In file included from C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/SparseCore:30,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/Sparse:19,
                 from C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\matrix_ops.h:24:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseMatrixBase.h: In instantiation of 'class Eigen::SparseMatrixBase<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 0, int> >':
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseCompressedBase.h:26:7:   required from 'class Eigen::SparseCompressedBase<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 0, int> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseMatrix.h:92:7:   required from 'class Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 0, int>'
ann/ann.h:61:44:   required from here
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseMatrixBase.h:42:30: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<float>::type' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes]
   42 |                      >::type PacketReturnType;
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h: In instantiation of 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>, 0>':
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:282:7:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>, 1>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:519:7:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>, 3>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:426:8:   required from 'struct Eigen::internal::special_scalar_op_base<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>, float, float, false>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:41:34:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:48:34:   required from 'class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:91:7:   required from 'class Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:128:7:   required from 'class Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>'
ann/ann.h:82:50:   required from here
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:55:30: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<float>::type' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes] 
   55 |                      >::type PacketReturnType;
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h: In instantiation of 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1>, 0>':
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:282:7:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1>, 1>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:519:7:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1>, 3>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:426:8:   required from 'struct Eigen::internal::special_scalar_op_base<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1>, float, float, false>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:41:34:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:48:34:   required from 'class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:91:7:   required from 'class Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:128:7:   required from 'class Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1>'
ann/ann_impl.h:180:99:   required from here
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:55:30: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<float>::type' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes] 
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h: In instantiation of 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> >, 0>':
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:282:7:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> >, 1>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:519:7:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> >, 3>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:426:8:   required from 'struct Eigen::internal::special_scalar_op_base<Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> >, float, float, false>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:41:34:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> > >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/ArrayBase.h:39:34:   required from 'class Eigen::ArrayBase<Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> > >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/ArrayWrapper.h:41:7:   required from 'class Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 1> >'
ann/ann_impl.h:337:43:   required from here
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:55:30: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<float>::type' {aka '__m128'} [-Wignored-attributes] 
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h: In instantiation of 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, 0>':
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:282:7:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, 1>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:519:7:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, 3>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:426:8:   required from 'struct Eigen::internal::special_scalar_op_base<Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >, float, float, false>'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:41:34:   required from 'class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> > >'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fyp stuff\Giraffe-master\Eigen/src/Core/ArrayBase.h:39:34:   required from 'class Eigen::ArrayBase<Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> > >'
```

I have attached a screenshot if it helps. Not sure what the highlighted purple means?

Heres an album of the terminal output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8PWk.jpg

Are the purple messages warnings that I need to resolve? Im still getting an output but not sure if these warnings are causing some incorrect values. Seems like all of them are a result of wignoredattribute?

Comment: How do you compile in Visual Studio Code? You can have a build task, or you can just run from the command line. I'm sure there are other ways with other plug ins. The warnings look to all be on Eigen code. I'd ignore those. Depending on how you're compiling, you can turn those warnings off. It's possible that there's something wrong with the Eigen library, but the issue with your output is most likely in your code or (depending on how janky Giraffe is) the Giraffe code. Note, I know nothing about Giraffe, so I have no idea how established of a library it is.

Comment: That's only part of the output, most lines have been cut off, and some of it has been badly mangled.

Comment: The fact that the amount of people running code from their Desktop folder isn't 0 is surreal to me.

Comment: It looks like it's emitting warnings that are ~160 characters before line wrapping, but your console is only showing the first ~80 characters before each line and then just... dropping the second half of each line? Several of those lines end in `wa` which is supposed to be `warning`, but the rest of the warning is missing

Comment: @sweenish Not only Desktop, but Admin/Desktop too! The space in the path is just icing on the cake. :)

Comment: @JohnFilleau it is compiled in command line if that affects anything. Seems like everything is a result of Wignored-attribute?

Comment: @molbdnilo i believe my edit has the full line now. sorry bout that.

Comment: @sweenish not sure how that relates to the question but sure